# How to get the right target when submitting a form in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, target

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {

});
```

When user submits the form by click `<input type="submit" />`,it should be `<input type="submit" />`,

when user submits the form by pressing `Enter` in a `<input />`,it should be that `<input />`

I tried `event.target`,but it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = null;
    $('#form :input').focus(function() {
        target = this;
        alert(target);
    });
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        alert(target);
    });
});
```

Comment: this.target is indeed wrong, just tried myself. Will remove it promptly.

Comment: @unknown (google) - I've edited the answer, it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks.I'm not sure if there is a more simple solution,though

Answer (score 0):

When pressing enter in a filed or by clicking on a `<input type="submit" />` it's the `<form>`  that is submitted.

So the target is the one specified by your your `<form>` tag identified by `#form` in your example.

I'm not shure what you want to do though...